# Why is this an unreachable statement? Java

Tags: java, oop, unreachable-statement

The unreachable statement is: `thisCustomer = findCustomer(theCustomerID);`. I cannot figure out why. `thisCustomer` is an attribute of `Customer` object, `findCustomer()` is a method listed below, and `theCustomerID` is the parameter of the method this statement is in.  The problem is in rentOutApt(int theAptID, int theCustomerID, int theMonthsToRent) //3.  This code is toward the bottom.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator; // If you choose to use one.

/**
 * .AptRentalAgency.
 * Controller class.
 * 
 * Name: 
 * Comment: 
 * 
 * For Dr. Nikhil Srinivasan's MIST 4600 Exam02 on 20140321.
 * 
 * @author Dr. Nikhil Srinivasan
 * @version 20140317
 * 
 */

public class AptRentalAgency
{
    // instance variables

    private int currentDate;
    // These match the Customer objects:
    private int customerID;
    private String customerName;
    private double customerBalance; 
    private int customerAptID; // 0 if he or she does not currently have a apartment.
    private int customerCreditRating;

    // These match the Apartment objects:
    private int aptID;
    private String aptName;
    private String aptAddress;
    private int aptSize;
    private double aptRent;

    // ****** The following are set when the apt is rented:
    private int aptCustomerID; // 0 if not rented.
    private double aptDeposit; // 0 if not rented
    private int aptMonthsRented; // 0 if not rented.
    private int aptRentalDate; // 0 if not rented.

    // There are a number of important nonfields that are to be computed 
    //  in their accessor (get) methods as needed:
    private double aptDepositMultiplier;
    private double aptTotalCost;

    // These are for the current Customer and current Apt objects:
    Customer thisCustomer;
    Apartment thisApt;

    // These are the needed ArrayLists:
    ArrayList<Customer> customers;
    ArrayList<Apartment> apts;

    // ReadFile objects:
    private ReadFile aptReader; // Declare a ReadFile object to read from the AptData.txt file.
    private ReadFile customerReader; // Declare a ReadFile object to read from the customerData.txt file.

    /**
     * AptRentalAgency Constructor
     */
    public AptRentalAgency()
    {
        // Set the currentDate:
        currentDate = 20140321;

        // Create the ArrayLists:
        customers = new ArrayList<Customer>();
        apts = new ArrayList<Apartment>();

        // Read in the Apt objects and Customer objects. Load them into the ArrayLists.
        readApts();
        readCustomers();
    }

    /**
     * .readApts.
     * Reads in the Apt objects.
     */
    private void readApts()
    {
        aptReader = new ReadFile("AptData.txt");
        aptReader.setSeparator(",");
        // Read and Load the Data:
        for(aptReader.readInputLine(); !aptReader.eof(); aptReader.readInputLine())
        {
            // Load the data into fields
            aptID = aptReader.getIntField(1);
            aptName = aptReader.getStringField(2);
            aptAddress = aptReader.getStringField(3);
            aptSize = aptReader.getIntField(4);
            aptRent = aptReader.getDoubleField(5);
            aptCustomerID = aptReader.getIntField(6);
            aptDeposit = aptReader.getDoubleField(7);
            aptMonthsRented = aptReader.getIntField(8);
            aptRentalDate = aptReader.getIntField(9);

            // Construct thisApt
            thisApt = new Apartment(aptID, aptName, aptAddress, aptSize, aptRent, 
                aptCustomerID, aptDeposit, aptMonthsRented, aptRentalDate);

            // Add thisApt to the apts ArrayList.
            apts.add(thisApt);
        }
        // End of Loop
        System.out.println("\nAll apts read from the file and added to the ArrayList.\n");
    }

    /**
     * .readCustomers.
     * Reads in the Customer objects.
     */
    private void readCustomers()
    {
        customerReader = new ReadFile("CustomerData.txt");

        customerReader.setSeparator(",");
        // Read and Load the Data:
        for(customerReader.readInputLine(); !customerReader.eof(); customerReader.readInputLine())
        {
            // Load the data into fields
            customerID = customerReader.getIntField(1);
            customerName = customerReader.getStringField(2);
            customerBalance = customerReader.getDoubleField(3);
            customerAptID = customerReader.getIntField(4);
            customerCreditRating = customerReader.getIntField(5);

            // Construct thisCustomer
            thisCustomer = new Customer(customerID, customerName, customerBalance, customerAptID, customerCreditRating);

            // Add thisCustomer to the customers ArrayList.
            customers.add(thisCustomer);
        }
        // End of Loop
        System.out.println("\nAll customers read from the file and added to the ArrayList.\n");
    }

    /**
     * .printAllCustomers.
     */
    public void printAllCustomers()
    {
        // Print a header, then the list.
        System.out.println("\nCurrent Customer List on " + currentDate + "\n");
        System.out.println("CustID  Name                        Balance Apt ID  CreditRating");
        System.out.println("------  -----------------           ------- ------- ------------");
        for(Customer theCustomer: customers)
        {
            theCustomer.printInfo();
        }
        System.out.println("\nEnd of Customer List. \n");
    }

    /**
     * .printAllApts.
     */
    public void printAllApts()
    {
        // Print a header, then the list.
        System.out.println("\nCurrent Apt List on " + currentDate + "\n");
        System.out.println("AptID   Apt Name                Address                    Size   Rent    RenterID Deposit MonthsRented RentalDate");
        System.out.println("-----  -------------------      -------------------------- ----   ------- -------- ------- ------------ ----------");
        for(Apartment theApt: apts)
        {
            theApt.printInfo();
        }
        System.out.println("\nEnd of Apt List. \n");
    }

    // ****************** Do your work after this point ********************************

    /**
     * .find a customer.
     */
    public Customer findCustomer(int theCustomerID)
    {
        for(Customer theCustomer: customers)
        {
            if (theCustomer.getCustomerID() == theCustomerID)
            {
                return theCustomer;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * .find Apartment.
     */
    public Apartment findApartment(int theAptID)
    {
        for(Apartment theApt: apts)
        {
            if (theApt.getAptID() == theAptID)
            {
                return theApt;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * .customerAddMoney.
     * Part a
     */
    public void customerAddMoney(int theCustomerID, double theAmountToAdd)
    {
        // Find the customer, If the Customer does not exist print a message and return(exit the method)
        thisCustomer = findCustomer(theCustomerID);

        // Check the amount provided to see if it is less than zero. If it is less than zero then print a message and return(exit the method)
        if( thisCustomer == null)
        {
            System.out.println("Customer " + theCustomerID + " does not exist. Returning!");
            return;
        }

        // Update the customer balance by adding the amount to the existing customer balance.
        double customerBalance = thisCustomer.getCustomerBalance() + theAmountToAdd;
        thisCustomer.setCustomerBalance(customerBalance);
    }

    /**
     * .checkOutApt.
     * Parts b and c.
     */
    public void rentOutApt(int theAptID, int theCustomerID, int theMonthsToRent)
    {
        // PART B:
        // 1 Find the specific theAptID Apartment object and load it into thisApt. 
        // If null, print a message that the apt does not exist and return.
        thisApt = findApartment(theAptID);

        // 2 Verify that thisApt Apartment is available (not rented out to a customer). 
        //    If not, print a message that the apt is already rented out and return.
        if(thisApt.getAptRentalDate() == 0)
        {
            System.out.println("Apartment " + theAptID + " is available. Returning!");
            return;
        }
        else
        {  
            System.out.println("Apartment " + theAptID + " is rented out. Returning!");
            return;
        }

        // 3 Find the specific theCustomerID object and load it into thisCustomer. 
        // If null, print a message that the customer does not exist and return.
        thisCustomer = findCustomer(theCustomerID);
        if(thisCustomer == null)
        {
            System.out.println("Customer " + theCustomerID + " does not exist. Returning!");
            return;
        }


        // 4 Verify that thisCustomer Customer does not already have an apartment. 
        //   If he or she does, print a message that the customer already has an apartment
        //   and return.
        if(thisCustomer.getCustomerAptID() != 0)
        {
            System.out.println("*** Customer is already living in: " + customerAptID);
            return;
        }


        // 5 Verify that the thisCustomer Customer has enough money to rent the apt.
        // The initial payment from a customer to rent an apartmentis the sum of the calculated 
        // deposit based on customer credit rating (the getAptDepositAmount method)
        // and the first month's rent.
        //   
        //   You will need to get the theCustomer’s balance and compare it to the sum of  
        //   thisApt (getAptRent and getAptDepositAmount methods). 
        double customerBalance = thisApt.getAptDepositAmount(thisCustomer.getCustomerCreditRating()) + thisApt.getAptRent();
        if(customerBalance > thisCustomer.getCustomerBalance())
        {
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("The customer does not have enough money.");
            System.out.println("The customer is " + customerBalance + " short.");
            System.out.println();
            return;
        }


        // PART C:
        // 6 Now check out theAptID Apt object to thisCustomer Customer object. 
        //   In thisCustomer, set customerAptID to theAptID.
        thisCustomer.setCustomerAptID(theAptID);


        // In thisApt, set 
        //   * aptCustomerID to theCustomerID
        thisApt.setAptCustomerID(theCustomerID);

        // In thisApt, set  
        //  * aptDeposit to the deposit amount you find after using the 
        //    getAptDepositAmount(int custCreditRating) method in Apartment Class
        thisApt.setAptDeposit(thisApt.getAptDepositAmount(thisCustomer.getCustomerCreditRating()));


        // set  * aptMonthsRented  theMonthsToRent
        thisApt.setAptMonthsRented(theMonthsToRent);


        //   * aptRentalDate to currentDate
        thisApt.setAptRentalDate(currentDate);


    }

}
```

Comment: Error in the code. You are closing the method already before the statement.

Comment: it doesn't look like it's in the method

Comment: Match your curly braces carefully.

Comment: You can't have code outside of a method.  (Aside from simple member initializers, that is.)  There's no way for that code to be invoked.

Comment: This is where getting the IDE to indent your code makes a *huge* difference...

Comment: I added the method the statement is inside of, sorry.

Comment: @Michael With your update, the error you posted can't happen. Post your real code, please.

Comment: Posted the whole code.

Comment: This is why its important to give the full context: The if/else before has a return in both branches, so this the answer.

Comment: I did not want everyone to have to read through the entire source code.  Thank you so much for helping!  I will follow your mentioned conventions in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lines 237-246 are:

```
if(thisApt.getAptRentalDate() == 0)
{
    System.out.println("Apartment " + theAptID + " is available. Returning!");
    return;
}
else
{  
    System.out.println("Apartment " + theAptID + " is rented out. Returning!");
    return;
}
```

This is guaranteed to return. The output is different depending on the result of `thisApt.getAptRentalDate()`, but both conditions return.

Everything after that is therefore unreachable code. Since `thisCustomer = findCustomer(theCustomerID);` is on line 250, it is unreachable, as well as all other code in that method.